# ¿Origen de "género" como "mercancía"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, acepciones

Una de las acepciones de la palabra "género" es, según la RAE, es

> 4. m. En el comercio, **mercancía** (‖ cosa mueble).

Se utiliza en expresiones como

> Hemos agotado todo el género, hay que reponer.

Esta frase se puede oír en algunas tiendas. De hecho, oírla es lo que ha hecho que a un amigo le asalte esta pregunta, por lo que la publico aquí:

¿De dónde viene este uso? Es decir, ¿cuál es la relación entre la mercancía que se vende y la palabra "género"? ¿Cómo se conectaron?

Answer (score 1):

Ya en el en [Diccionario de Autoridades](http://web.frl.es/DA.html) (1734) se recoge:

> **Generos**:
>   Se llaman tambien las mercancías, assí de texidos, como de drogas, con las quales se trata y comércia. Latín. *Mercium genera*.

Comment: Dado que la definición del _Autoridades_ incluye una traducción al latín como "mercium genera", eso indica que ya en latín se usaba la palabra "género" para las mercancías. Tal vez convendría trasladar pues esta pregunta a [Latin.SE].

Answer (score 1):

Hay que remontarse al latín para entender este significado. Originalmente, el verbo *[gĕnĕro](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:alphabetic%20letter=G:entry%20group=5:entry=genero&toc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DG%3Aentry%20group%3D6)* significaba "engendrar, procrear, crear" pero también "producir", aunque este significado pudo ser más tardío. En la definición de *[gĕnus , ĕris](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DG%3Aentry%20group%3D6%3Aentry%3Dgenus1)* leemos que su primer significado fue el literal: "nacimiento, descendencia, origen", pero también "raza, estirpe". De ahí se generó un significado transferido:

> De un conjunto de objetos (personas, animales, plantas, cosas inanimadas o abstractas) que están relacionados o se relacionan entre sí como consecuencia de una semejanza en las cualidades naturales: *raza, stock, clase, género, especie, tipo*.

Se entiende pues como *género* aquello que es *generado* o *producido* y tiene características comunes. En latín *mercium genera* significa literalmente "mercancías", aquel género con el que se puede comerciar.